# $().ajaxStart not firing

Tags: jquery

I have this at the top of my jQuery script:

```
   $().ajaxStart(function() {
      alert('ok');
   });
```

But the alert is not firing.
All the other ajax is working, so I'm not sure why this isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) on document:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

`$().ajaxStart` worked before jQuery 1.4 but no more.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){alert("aa");});
```

HTH